how to automate and implement Rich Text Tile pictures to be loaded as lazy in Sitecore
I am trying to implement and automate Rich Text Tile pictures to be loaded as lazy functionality. Also to mention I am not using SXA.
Is there any way to automate it instead of manually adding  loading="lazy" attribute?

You likely would need include a post processing  on save. Or override how sitecore renders links. Though browsers should by default lazy load images that are not in view.

In order to append the lazy loading attribute to the images that are there on the rich text editor, you will need to add custom processor inside the renderfield pipeline as below.

Custom the processor as below that fetch the images inside the rich text and then adds the lazy value inside the loading attribute to it.

using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField;
using System.Linq;

public class AddLazyLoading
{
   public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
   {
      if (args.FieldTypeKey == "rich text")
      {
         var richTextHtml = args.Result.FirstPart;
         var doc = new HtmlDocument();
         doc.LoadHtml(richTextHtml);
         var imageNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
         if (imageNodes != null && imageNodes.Any())
         {
            foreach (var imageNode in imageNodes)
            {
               imageNode.Attributes.Append("loading", "lazy");
            }
         }
         args.Result.FirstPart = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
      }
   }
}


Thereafter patch the above processor inside the renderfield pipeline as below.

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines> 
      <renderField>
        <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.ExpandLinks, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="SitecoreCustomExtensions.Pipelines.AddLazyLoading,SitecoreCustomExtensions" resolve="true" />
      </renderField>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Using this way all the images that are there in the rich text, will have the lazy value added in the loading attribute automatically.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

Thanks much Chirag!!

Create a Custom Processor for Rich Text Rendering:
You can create a custom pipeline processor for Sitecore's renderField pipeline. This allows you to intercept the rendering of fields (such as the Rich Text field) and modify the output, adding the loading="lazy" attribute to images automatically.
Create the Processor Class
In your solution, create a custom processor that extends the renderField pipeline to manipulate the rendered output of Rich Text fields.
using System.Web;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;

public class LazyLoadImageProcessor
{
    public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
    {
        if (args == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Result.FirstPart))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Only apply for Rich Text fields
        if (args.FieldTypeKey == "rich text")
        {
            // Modify the output HTML and add loading="lazy" to <img> tags
            args.Result.FirstPart = AddLazyLoadingToImages(args.Result.FirstPart);
        }
    }

    private string AddLazyLoadingToImages(string html)
    {
        // Regular expression to find <img> tags and add loading="lazy" attribute
        var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<img([^>]*)>");
        return regex.Replace(html, match => AddLazyAttribute(match.Value));
    }

    private string AddLazyAttribute(string imgTag)
    {
        // If the img tag already contains a loading attribute, skip it
        if (imgTag.Contains("loading="))
        {
            return imgTag;
        }
        // Insert loading="lazy" into the img tag
        return imgTag.Replace("<img", "<img loading=\"lazy\"");
    }
}

Register the Processor in renderField Pipeline
You need to register this processor in the renderField pipeline in the Sitecore.Pipelines.config or your custom configuration file.
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <renderField>
        <!-- Add the custom processor for lazy loading -->
        <processor type="YourNamespace.LazyLoadImageProcessor, YourAssemblyName" />
      </renderField>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Ensure Compatibility with Sitecore Editor:
Sitecore's Rich Text Editor might strip out certain attributes during editing. Ensure that the loading="lazy" attribute is not removed by adjusting the allowed attributes in the HTML editor configurations, if necessary.
In Sitecore.config, under the HTML Editor section, you can ensure that custom attributes like loading are allowed.
<setting name="HtmlEditor.RemoveAttributes" value="onabort,onblur,..." />

